# Manual how to use grunt-bake

Tags: gruntjs

pls help to tune work with grunt-bake. May be someone can help with a good article about it or clear and sipmle example how to work with. I'm looking for smth that is more understandable than description at npmjs.com. Any kind of help will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is all explained detailed:
https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake